# Applying special permission suid & sgid

Tags: linux, setuid, setgid

I was in the processs of learning a bit about the special permission in Linux. Where is find certain anomilies.

`suid` - For executable/files where user subsume the `UID`/permission of  the owner. With `UID` range ~1-100.

`sgid` - For directories - `GID`, where `GID` is subsumed and any file and or subdirtory holds the permission of original group instead of the creator's group.

However when I apply the permission using `chmod +s test`, the system applies a blanket permission over both owner and group irrespective of the file type.

I know the representations is same for both `s` but shouldn't that be applied judiciously with file type in mind?

For e.g :- I created a normal file `test` and applied the aforementioned command. What surprises me is despite being a `normal` file type the command is also applied on the `group` side as well.

```
~$ chmod +s test
~$ ls -l test
-rwSr-sr-x 1 shashwat shashwat 0 Jan 27 13:14 test
~$ file test
test: setuid, setgid, empty
```

Is that normal? What kind of repercussion can occur from that kind file permission?

Regards

Comment: I think your description of suid and sgid are wrong.

Comment: Use `g+s` or `u+s` then.

Comment: @Kusalananda That was insightful, I  didn't knew I can do that.